# Making relationship class between feature class and Excel table with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, excel, feature-class, relationship-class

I have a feature class of parcels and an Excel table of other information related to those parcels. Goal: would like edits from an Excel table to get passed onto feature class. Problem: for a true ArcGIS "relationship class" both items have to reside in same geodatabase, and I cannot have the Excel table in the geodatabase.

What is the best workflow for relating an Excel table to an ArcMap Feature class where edits get passed onto one another, in either direction. I know "relates" are temporary until you export to new feature class. I am confused on how to have an Excel table linked to feature class where the relationship is permanent but the data is dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

If it existed I think the term Esri might use for this would be a live link between a geodatabase feature class and an Excel table.

This does not exist so I think you would need to support/submit an ArcGIS Idea for it.

The closest I can find is [Ability to Connect to Geodatabase Feature Class Tables in Excel/Access](https://community.esri.com/ideas/9816).

It is not an enhancement that I would vote for because Excel is not designed to be a database.  I think you would be better converting your Excel table to a geodatabase table, implementing a relationship class, and maintaining your data there.